# How to give people tools using a remote event?

Tags: lua, client-server, game-engine, roblox

I have a local script that says when a part is clicked it will send the name of the player to the serverside for handing out the weapon. When the the event is fired it goes to this code in the server script side

```lua
ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent:OnServerEvent:Connect(function(playerWhoWantsTool)
     local toolClone = tool:Clone()
     print(playerWhoWantsTool)-- It prints out my username in the output so I know it works
     local buyersBackPack = game.Players.playerWhowantsTool.Backpack
     toolClone.Parent = buyersBackPack
     -- Returns an error about cant find playerwhowantsTool in game.Players
end)
```

I'm not sure how to go about giving a player a tool with a server script,Thanks.

I was expecting for the identified player to receive the tool in their backpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But when you call a [RemoteEvent](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent)'s [FireServer](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent#FireServer) function, the [OnServerEvent](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent#OnServerEvent) event will provide the player that fired the event as the first argument. That variable is a [Player](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player) object, so you have access to the Backpack right from that object. You don't need to index into the Players service to find the player again.

```
ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent:OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
     local toolClone = tool:Clone()
     toolClone.Parent = player.Backpack
end)
```

Comment: Wow, Great Response Time! That makes a lot of sense now that you say it, it works perfectly fine now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Local script
local button = script.Parent

button.Activated:Connect(function()
    game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent:FireServer(tool) -- fire the event
end)

-- Server script
amount = 250
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(plr, tool)
    -- check somehow if the player has enough money or smth
    if plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value <= amount then -- amount to buy tool
         plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value -= amount -- takes away amount
              script.Tool:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack -- get the tool from the script and give to plr
        end
    end)
```